# Eclipse: Include required features to update site

Tags: eclipse, update-site

I am developing an Eclipse plug-in that requires a third-party plug-in such as the AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools) plug-in. 
When a user wants to install my plug-in from the update site and does not have AJDT installed or enabled in his list of available update sites the installation will fail.

I created a file associateSites.xml next to the site.xml and included the reference in site.xml:  tag:

```
<site
  associateSitesURL="associateSites.xml">
```

The content of associateSites.xml looks like this:

```
<associateSites>
<associateSite url="..."/>
</associateSites>
```

This does not seem to have the wanted effect. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Any luck? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using associateSitesURL seems to be deprecated.

This can help:

[Include an external update site in my update site in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398070/include-an-external-update-site-in-my-update-site-in-eclipse)

together with

[Feature Export Wizard](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_sitemap.html)

You have to add the

```
<repository-reference location=...>
```

tag in the category.xml and export the features as described in [Feature Export Wizard](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_sitemap.html), checking the option "Categorize repository".

Answer (score -1):

Try making the associateSitesURL an absolute URL (eg, `http://www.yourdomain.com/updates/associateSites.xml`)