# Include an external update site in my update site in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, update-site

I have an update site in which I'm including my features, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <feature url="features/my_feature1_1.0.0.qualifier.jar" id="my_feature1" version="1.0.0.qualifier">
      <category name="My Category"/>
   </feature>
   <feature url="features/my_feature2_1.0.0.qualifier.jar" id="my_feature2" version="1.0.0.qualifier">
      <category name="My Category"/>
   </feature>
   ...
</site>
```

Some of the plugins included by those features have dependencies on plugins that I download from other updates sites, right now I have to manually install those update sites before installing mine, to automate this, I can download and include those dependencies to my site.xml but at the end the .zip will contain them and the size will be too big, is there a way to link an external update site to mine so it is automatically downloaded during the installation of my update site?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a `associateSitesURL` tag that provides this behavior for *site.xml*. That being said, it looks like *site.xml* has been replaced in favor of *category.xml* (see for instance [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4946197/10226142)) and I don't know whether this tag is still supported.

Vogella has [a section about how to create one](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#create-a-category-definition-file-for-the-update-site). Using a *category.xml* file, you can specify an additional update site by adding a `repository-reference` tag. For instance, add the following code to the *category.xml* file to reference an Orbit update site:

```xml
<repository-reference location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20170818183741/repository" enabled="true" />
```

The URL can also be specified directly from the *category.xml* file editor:

[image: category.xml file editor]

I failed to find any documentation on this but I used it in a side project and it seemed to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using an element like this `<repository-reference location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12" enabled="true" />` in `category.xml`. See the article [Eclipse p2 site references](https://www.lorenzobettini.it/2021/09/eclipse-p2-site-references/) for details.